# Curved (not rounded) border of an HTML element

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

In my particular case, I need to have an image's bottom border look like this:

[image: example border]

The image is not warped, just parts of the image are cut off by the border curve at the bottom. Of course, I can edit the image and make that section transparent to achieve the desired effect, but I'm wondering how to do it with CSS or possibly JavaScript. The image needs to be able to have a relative size (i.e. possible to set `width: 100%` on it), and the curve should be proportional to the size of the image.

I've looked into HTML canvas for the first time and I can define a rectangular clipping region with a Bezier curve at the bottom, and draw the image inside the clipped context, but it seems it can't satisfy the relative size requirement.

But can a similar effect be achieved with a simpler solution, possibly without using canvas?

Comment: is the transparency important or can it be a solid color mask?

Comment: Transparency would be nice, but I'd really like to see your solid color mask solution, please.

Answer (score 4):

You can use either SVG or html5 Canvas to clip your img into your rect with  curved bottom.

Here's how to do it with html5 Canvas:

1. Create an html5 canvas.
2. Define your rectangle with curved bottom using Path commands.
3. Create a clipping region from the path
4. Draw the image object into the canvas. It will only display inside the clipping region.
5. You can use `context.scale` to adjust the size of your path and image as desired.

[image]

```js
var img=new Image();
img.onload=start;
img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/jellybeans.jpg";
function start(){
    document.getElementById('container').appendChild(clippedImg(img,100,100,0.25,0.50));
    document.getElementById('container').appendChild(clippedImg(img,100,100,0.25,1.00));
    document.getElementById('container').appendChild(clippedImg(img,100,100,0.25,2.00));
}


function clippedImg(img,w,h,curvePct,scaleFactor){
    var c=document.createElement('canvas');
    var ctx=c.getContext('2d');
    c.width=w*scaleFactor;
    c.height=h*(1+curvePct)*scaleFactor;
    ctx.scale(scaleFactor,scaleFactor);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(0,h);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(w/4,h*(1-curvePct),w*3/4,h*(1+curvePct),w,h);
    ctx.lineTo(w,0);
    ctx.lineTo(0,0);
    ctx.lineTo(0,h);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.clip();
    ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
    return(c);
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
canvas{margin:5px;}
```

```html
<h4>Clipped image into an html5 canvas</h4>
<div id=container></div>
```

Comment: This is what I've tried, but in this case the image needs to be of a fixed size, correct?

Comment: @p4sh4. You can scale both the path and the contained image using `context.scale`. I've updated my example to include a scalable size. :-)

Comment: Awesome answer, thanks! Perhaps I haven't expressed myself clearly - I needed to make the image "responsive", so it can change size based on the browser window size. I've achieved it by redrawing it on the window resize event with the new width. Thanks again for such a thorough answer!

Comment: Interesting approach tho the edges aren't as smooth

Answer (score 1):

You could try this CSS Trick:

```
.masked { position:relative; }

.masked:after {
   position:absolute;
   width:100%;
   display:block;
   content: "";
   background:url(myImgMask.png/svg);
   height:10px;
   left:0;
   right:0;
   bottom:0;
}
```

**Explanation**

Basically you will have to create a PNG or SVG image which is transparent at the top (above the curve) and has a solid color fill (e.g. white) and then place it on top of your element through a pseudo selector (`:after`)

Comment: .masked is not an IMG tag ( because IMG can't have :after ). It should be wrapper.

Comment: yes, that is true. The final HTML would look like this: `.masked > img + (:after)`

Answer (score 1):

Sine wave bottom border.

```js
var img = document.getElementById('my_img');
img.width = 100;
img.height = 100;

function genSnow(img) {
  var can = document.createElement('canvas');
  var w = can.width = img.width;
  var h = can.height = img.height;
  var ctx = can.getContext('2d');
  var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, w, h);
  var d = imageData.data;

  for (var i = 0; i < d.length; i += 4) {
    d[i] = d[i + 1] = d[i + 2] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 128);
    d[i + 3] = 255;
  }

  ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
  img.src = can.toDataURL();
}


img.onload = function() {
  img.onload = null;
  sineBorder(this, 10, 2);
};

genSnow(img);


function sineBorder(img, heightPercent, ocillations) {
  if (!ocillations) ocillations = 2;
  if (!heightPercent) heightPercent = 20;
  heightPercent /= 100;
  
  var can = document.createElement('canvas');
  var w = can.width = img.width;
  var h = can.height = img.height;
  var ctx = can.getContext('2d');
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, w, h);
  var d = imageData.data;
  var o = (ocillations * Math.PI) / img.width;
  var hi = (h * heightPercent);
  var a = 0;
  
  for (var x = 0; x < img.width; x++) {
    var s = Math.sin(a)  * hi;
    var y = Math.floor(h - hi - s);
    
    for (;y < h; y++) {
      var i = ((w * 4) * y) + (x * 4);
      d[i] = 255;
      d[i+1] = 0;
      d[i+2] = 0;
      d[i+3] = 0;
    }
    a += o;
  }

  ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
  img.src = can.toDataURL();

}
```

```html
<img id="my_img" src="">
```